# Is it possible for PHP to use the HTML 5 geolocation without using a javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Is it be possible for php to use HTML 5 geolocation?

The idea is the **navigator.geolocation** can be used only using javascript.But what if the device turn off its javascript or no javascript support.

PHP can pull out the **navigator.userAgent** and they do it by **$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']**.
I dunno how they do it so there should be a way to use the PHP to access navigator.geolocation without using javascript.The question is how?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot. Php works on server and haven't any access to client's browser.

Php's work is finished when html is completely generated. After that complete html is passed to the client through network.

Comment: So how did they identify useragent?

Comment: @khem: yes, you can try to **guess** the useragent, since `HTTP_USER_AGENT` is untrusted variable and anything can be put there. And even you guessed right - you still haven't an access to the client because - look at my answer. Let's suppose I said to you that I'm driving porsche 911. So what? Can you do something with my car? No. You just know its model, nothing more. You cannot even be sure that I did not lie.

Comment: The user agent would be sent in the packet header with the request.

Comment: Ok you are right with that. But there is something sending an info from browser using HTTP headers.

Comment: @Zurahn: was it to me? So? You think I don't know it? ;-) And to be clear - there is no term `packet header` applied to http.

Comment: @khem: something what? Install firebug and see what headers your browser sends each request.

Comment: In firebug the navigator.geolocation is not visible or what it is doing.

Comment: @khem: that is because it is not passed to the server.

Comment: And where it is passed?The navigator.geolocation works when there is an internet connection.

Comment: @khem: it is not passed anywhere. It is just DOM object. http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html

Comment: @zerkms thank you for your time.DOM/JS it won't work when js/ecma is turned off.I think I'll need to switch to IP geolocation API if the js/ecma is turned off..

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers send the user-agent with the HTTP request, and that's why your server has access to the user agent.

But as far as I know, no browser sends location info along with the HTTP request, so your server script doesn't have access to that data.

The best you can do on the server without help of JavaScript is to guess the location based on the IP.

However, if your user has JavaScript enabled, you can send the location to the server somehow (like, AJAX request and store in session or profile, or store the coordinates in a hidden input field), and degrade to guessing by IP when the user doesn't have JavaScript enabled.

Comment: Thank you for your time.I already did that the only problem is (if javascript is turn off)...